# How to optimize a linear problem with quadratic constraints?

Tags: optimization, quadratics, matlab

I need help with finding an algorithm, preferable in MatLab to optimize the following problem

> $$ \max \sum_{i=1}^N a_ix_i + b_i$$
> With constraints
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^N c_ix_i^2 + d_ix_i +e_i < C$$
>
> $$x \in \mathbb R \quad \quad \quad a,b,c,d,r,C \in \mathbb R $$

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the edit

Comment: Check the [fmincon function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

Comment: Use a QCQP solver. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_constrained_quadratic_program If your constraints are convex ($c_i\geq 0$) you will have a bigger choice.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you easily can solve this analytically? (i.e. no reason to use a numerical solver)

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I come from a software development background so I am not aware of an analytical solution, how would I come to one?

Comment: You use that the maximizer of $a^Tx$ over $x^Tx\leq 1$ is given by $a/\||x||_2$. Your problem is only a variable change away.

Comment: ...should be $a/||a||_2$